# How to use civiprofile for contact form

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, profile

I want to use a civi profile for our contact form, so that all inquiries and new contacts are stored in civi. I created the custom fields and have them on a new tab and table, so multiple submissions will be stored.   I am having two problems.

1. When the profile form is submitted it arrives in email with our organization's email address as the From address.  Can I set this so the person who submitted it is the From address?
2. We would like to show the date it was submitted on in the table, but the only option I can find is for the user to select the date manually before submitting it.  Is there a way to have the current date already pre-selected in view only mode on the profile?

Civi 5.3 on wordpress 4.9

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those are doable with a profile without writing an extension.  However, both should be quite doable using Caldera Forms with the CiviCRM integration plugin.  I suspect you could also use Contact Form 7 with the Form Processor plugin to get similar results.